# program on Big endian and little endian

Tags: c++, c, endianness, cpu-architecture

I was reading about little endian-big endian and came across these concept

```
   long long number 

(((number & 0x00000000000000ff) << 56) + 
 ((number & 0x000000000000ff00) << 40) + 
 ((number & 0x0000000000ff0000) << 24) +
 ((number & 0x00000000ff000000) << 8) + 
 ((number & 0x000000ff00000000) >> 8) + 
 ((number & 0x0000ff0000000000) >> 24) +
 ((number & 0x00ff000000000000) >> 40) +
 ((number & 0xff00000000000000) >> 56 ))
```

what basically it does ?

When i compile it using( gcc -lrt -lm program_name) .i get a warning saying

```
   integer constant is too large for ‘long’ type
```

Comment: Can you add what data type `number` is?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20741488/edit) your code to include the datatype

Comment: It better be unsigned longish long to avoid the 50% odds for a -1.  99.99% odds at this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That code performs a toggle between little endian and big endian for an unsigned 64 bit data type.

Look at the first sub-expression:

```
(number & 0x00000000000000ff) << 56
```

This masks out bits 0-7, and shifts them to the left by 56. So they now occupy bits 56-63.

And the next sub-expression:

```
(number & 0x000000000000ff00) << 40
```

This masks out bits 8-15, and shifts them to the left by 40. And so on, and so on.

If was writing the code I'd use bitwise or, `|`, rather than arithmetic addition, `+`, since that reads better in my view.

Comment: it does for long long but long long is of 8 byte(i.e 64 bit) so how come it starts from 56

Comment: It *starts* at 56 and will *end*, correctly, at 63

Comment: @zishan Because a byte is generally 8 bits long, ya know.

Comment: You still need to reason about signed or unsigned types - the final right-shift will go wrong for signed types.